# c# and Webforms - Using constants in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm looking for a way to use a constant (string) within HTML `<p>` tags.

e.g. suppose within a `\Utils\Constants.cs` static class I have:

```
public const string BoysName = "Percy";
```

and I want to use this on the front end directly, e.g.

```
<p>When the shop opened [useConstantHere] was the first through the door!</P>
```

to display

```
When the shop opened Percy was the first through the door!
```

I assume it's something like the below but I can't seem to get it working...

```
 <p>When the shop opened <% BoysName %> was the first through the door!</P>
```

Do I need to have a using statement in the code behind, or can I do it all from the aspx page? Is this even possible?

I've done a similar thing with controls, e.g. labels, text boxes etc but I'd like to do it as above.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried <%= Utils.Constants.BoysName %>

Comment: I've posted the complete solution below for anyone else who needs it

Comment: Why the down vote may I ask? - turns out the answer was pretty simple - but it's only simple once you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Adam here is the complete solution:

```
<p>When the shop opened <%= SolutionName.ProjectName.Utils.Constants.BoysName %> was the first through the door!</p>
```

No using statement is required in the code behind.